# os.path.join() doesn't return the right result

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run the code `os.path.join("aaa", "{:s.xml}")`, it returns `{:s.xml}` instead of `aaa\\{:s.xml}`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work just for paths.
`os.path.join(path, *paths)` joins one or more path components intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly one directory separator `(os.sep)`, following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. If a component is an absolute path, all of the previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path component (e.g., r'\foo') is encountered. If a component contains a drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.
if you wanna join to string

## This script clips all datasets in a folder

```
import arcpy
inFolder = "aaa"
resultsFolder = "{:s.xml}"
clipFeature = "aaa\\{:s.xml}"

# List feature classes
arcpy.env.workspace = inFolder
featureClassList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Loop through each feature class and clip
for featureClass in featureClassList:

    # Make the output path by concatenating strings
    outputPath = resultsFolder + featureClass
    # Clip the feature class
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(featureClass, clipFeature, outputPath)
```